# Create Javascript Object with variable names as keys

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

I would like to create an object from variables where the keys are the variable names, and the values are the variable values:

```
let username = "foo";
let password = "bar";

let request = {
    username: username,
    password: password
};
```

Resulting value of `request`:

```
{"username":"foo","password":"bar"}
```

**Can this be done more simply, without writing `username` or `password` or any other variable name twice per object attribute?**

Comment: `let request = {username, password}` not supported in old crappy browsers tho.

Comment: Really... I remember trying it a while ago, didn't work..

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Works in latest Chrome, Firefox and MsEdge. Rest I do not bother trying.

Comment: Tried it... works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript 6 introduced shorthand property notation, which created a property with the key as the name of the variable, and the value as the value of the variable. It works like so:

```
let request = { username, password };
```

This will not work in older, less well-supported browsers however - Internet Explorer is (unfortunately) a good example.

To transpile it, you could use [Babel](https://babeljs.io), a popular transpiler.

Comment: FYI: Using babel transpiler solves the old browser support problem

Comment: Yeah, I know @aslantorret - but if you don't have, want or need Babel, it's easiest to know which features are supported and which aren't.